# Allow activeElement to be selected on mouse event

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap-typeahead

While trying to hover an item in the dropdown suggestions menu, I'm trying to make that item the `activeElement` and `activeIndex`. But the keyboard `up/down` arrow stops working with this change. I would like to have the `up/down` arrow key work as well from the activeIndex. How to do that? Here's the code i have

```
  public itemFocus = (e: any) => {
    let ce = e.currentTarget.id.toString();
    ce = ce.substring(ce.length - 1);
    this._typeahead.getInstance().setState({
      activeIndex: ce,
      activeItem: this.state.options[ce]});
  }
```

with idx denoting the iterator index of results

```
<MenuItem onMouseOver={this.itemFocus} key={idx} option={state} position={idx}>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be on the right track, though there are easier ways to get the index and data of the hovered item. The following should work:

**Note: The following solution is not officially supported by the API and could break without warning if the package internals change.**

```
<Typeahead
  options={[ ... ]}
  ref={(typeahead) => this._typeahead = typeahead}
  renderMenu={(filteredOptions, menuProps) => (
    <Menu {...menuProps}>
      {filteredOptions.map((option, index) => (
        <MenuItem
          onMouseOver={() => {
            this._typeahead.getInstance().setState({
              activeIndex: index,
              activeItem: option,
            });
          }}
          option={option}
          position={index}>
          {option}
        </MenuItem>
      ))}
    </Menu>
  )}
/>
```

Working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/ojz4kzn2vq

Comment: Is there a different approach needed to do the same when it comes to grouping menu items. The arrow keys dont work with those -> https://codesandbox.io/s/m751pvkn8p

Comment: The reason it's not working is because `idx` is being incremented in the upper scope and is therefore always `50` when the `onMouseOver` handler is called. You need to declare each item's index in the same scope where you're declaring the item. The following should work: https://codesandbox.io/s/wwv1jkyqp5